# Opencart filter module query statement, price and special price range

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Thanks for stopping by my question :)

I am developing a Opencart Filter Module for my webshop, but ran into a MySql query that is a bit of a nut to crack.

The purpose of the script is to return the amount of products that is found, by the given filter credentials:

- Minimum Price
- Maximum Price
- Category ID
- Manufacturer ID

The problem I have is getting the correct count of products when the min/max price is set. This is because that some products are on a sale. Meaning that it should check if the price is within the range of the special price, rather the normal price.

- Special price column is "ps.price"
- Product price is "p.price"

  ```
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, count(p.product_id) as count FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m 
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id) 
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
  LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id)
  WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND m.manufacturer_id = '" . $manufacturer_id . "'
  AND (ps.price BETWEEN '" . $min_price . "' AND '" . $max_price . "') 
  AND (p.price BETWEEN '" . $min_price . "' AND '" . $max_price . "') 
  AND p.status = 1
  ");
  $manufacturer_data = $query->rows;
  ```

What I need is somehow only make it select from the ps.price if it is not null , otherwise from the p.price column

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN ps.price IS NULL THEN p.price ELSE ps.price END product_price
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps ON (ps.product_id = p.product_id)
    WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' 
        AND m.manufacturer_id = '" . $manufacturer_id . "'
        AND (product_price BETWEEN '" . $min_price . "' AND '" . $max_price . "') 
        AND p.status = 1
");
```